# tikz parabola node position

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I am trying to position nodes on a parabola curve. However, it seems tikz cannot calculate the midway positions. Neither of the following examples works:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (-1,0) parabola[parabola height=2cm] (3,0)
        node[sloped, above, pos=0.5] {0.5};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[to path={
    parabola[parabola height=2cm] (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}]
    \draw (0,0) to
        node[above, sloped] {0.5} (3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: You can format your code examples by selecting the code and clicking on the 101 icon.  I fixed this for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the TikZ manual (section 16.8 “Placing Nodes on a Line or Curve Explicitly” in v2.10):

> In the simplest case, the previous
> path operation was a “line-to”
> operation, that is, a -- coordinate
> operation [...]
>
> The next case is the
> curve-to operation (the .. operation).
> [...]
>
> Another interesting case are the
> horizontal/vertical line-to operations
> |- and -|. For them, the position (or
> time) 0.5 is exactly the corner point.
> [...]
>
> **For all other path construction
> operations, *the position placement
> does not work***, currently. This will
> hopefully change in the future
> (especially for the arc operation).

(emphasis mine)

So you either have to position the node by hand, or draw the parabola with an explicit Bézier curve.