# Define node at relative coordinates of \draw plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes, plot

I am not able to fix that simple plot. I think I missed something, but I can't point out what ! 
Could you tell me why `(a)` is not at `midway` of the red line ?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:4]
\draw[very thin,color=gray] (-0.1,-1.1) grid (3.9,3.9);
\draw[->] (-0.2,0) -- (4.2,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-1.2) -- (0,4.2) node[above] {$f(x)$};
\draw[color=red] plot (\x,\x) node [midway,inner sep=0] (a) {} node[right] {$f(x) =x$};
\draw[->] (4,1) node[right] {this is not required (a)} -- (a) ;
\node[circle,fill,label={above left:this should be (a)}] at (2,2) {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Produced graph]

Is this a duplicate of [tikz-parabola-node-position](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9051/tikz-parabola-node-position) ?

Comment: It appears to be at the correct spot: (2,2) is midway for `f(x)=x` with the domain `0:4`?  Am I missing something?

Comment: @PeterGrill the large circle is not `(a)` that is to indicate where it should be. `(a)` is in fact at the origin. It looks like the `plot` option doesn't allow this kind of positioning.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `midway` (or `pos=0.5`) syntax doesn't work for TikZ plots (it would work if you used pgfplots to draw your plots).

However, you can use the `decorations.markings` library to define a coordinate along the path. Here's a style `mark position=<pos>(<coordinate name>)` that places a coordinate with a specified name at a specified distance along the path. You can call this multiple times if you need more than one position on a path.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}


\tikzset{
    mark position/.style args={#1(#2)}{
        postaction={
            decorate,
            decoration={
                markings,
                mark=at position #1 with \coordinate (#2);
            }
        }
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:4]
\draw[very thin,color=gray] (-0.1,-1.1) grid (3.9,3.9);
\draw[->] (-0.2,0) -- (4.2,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-1.2) -- (0,4.2) node[above] {$f(x)$};
\draw[color=red, mark position=0.5(a)] plot (\x,\x) node[right] {$f(x) =x$};
\node at (a) [left] {this is (a)};



\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Indeed, [here is another question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38763/how-to-place-a-node-in-the-middle-of-an-arc/) with a similar take on it. Probably @cjorssen has something to say about the latest status.

Comment: That's very nice. I was looking at decorations to solve this, but couldn't find a straightforward way. This looks very nice though!

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but my goal was to defined a node I could use after... I think I'll use pgfplots ! @percusse : indeed, cjorssen solve this using the CVS version of tokz... it's coming !

Comment: @Sigmun if you use a `\node` instead of a `\coordinate` you can also name your node with an additional argument. See my previous comment for a similar problem regarding arcs.

Comment: @Jake : This solves the simplified problem I give, but of course, my equation is not `(\x,\x)` but `(\x,{0.12/0.2*(0.2969*sqrt(\x )-0.126*\x -0.3516*\x^2 +0.2843*\x^3 -0.1015*\x^4 )})` and I get `! Dimension too large.` at compilation. Have you got a solution ? I see the [post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4404/tikz-multiple-decorations-on-a-path) which describe the same error. Any idea to solves that ?

Comment: If I just replace the `(\x,\x)` in my example with the new function, I don't get the error. Can you edit your question to include a MWE that reproduces the error?

Comment: @Jake : You right. The thing is I add `plot[smooth]` and obviously this is not a good idea ! So your solution still works without smoothed plot. Thank you very much !