# Positioning a node alongside a curve

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

What am I doing wrong ? Changing the value next to `pos=` doesn't move the node...

```
    \documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

    \usepackage{pgfplots}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \def\LimiTrace{6}
    \draw[blue,samples=100,line width=2pt] plot [domain=0:\LimiTrace] (\x,{(1-exp(-\x))*3}) node[pos=0.9] {$s(t)$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image: wrong node position along curve]

Comment: I don't think you're necessarily doing anything wrong, it's just that it doesn't work. See the similar questions https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128579/ and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43960

Comment: Where you like to have `s(t)`? right of end of figure? than try with `node[right] {$s(t)$}`.

Comment: I thought you could use `pos=0.5` like `midway` with more possibilities, but you can't. what a shame.

Comment: As @TorbjørnT. pointed out, this doesn't work like this for `plots` (and id does with `decorations.markings`) but since you are loading `pgfplots` you could just do `\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\def\LimiTrace{6}
\addplot[blue,samples=100,line width=2pt,domain=0:\LimiTrace] {(1-exp(-x))*3} 
node[pos=0.9,below] {$s(t)$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}` where this syntax works.

Comment: @marmot My current version is 1.14 .... so I'll see if can update it on all my PCs. Thanks

Comment: @LMT-PhD Version `1.14` also works. (I always add the compatibility mode in order to make the result reproducable.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answers in the comment, to sum up there are two possibilities:

- Add an option using marks to do the task
- Use a `\begin{axis}` and `\addplot` for which `pos=0.9` works as a node option.

The first is detailed in two ways there :

[tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128579](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128579) and [tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43960](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43960)

for the second :

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis} 
    \def\LimiTrace{6} 
    \addplot[blue,samples=100,
             line width=2pt,
             domain=0:\LimiTrace] {(1-exp(-x))*3} 
        node[pos=0.9,below] {$s(t)$}; 
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```